# How do I issue a code review in TFS after I have already checked in code?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, there is a pretty good TFS (Team Foundation Service) and in this TFS, you can request code reviews of your work among your peers.

The bad thing is that if you have already checked in your code, it complains and it does not allow you to issue a code review since it sees no changed in the code you have been working on locally.

How do I issue a code review in TFS after I have already checked in code?  Can I do it somehow as a comparison to a set of code I checked in earlier?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on a changeset in View History and click Request Review.

There are also links from the View Changeset panel in team explorer.